# /usr/bin/ld cannot find <library> only during compilation

Tags: c++, c, g++, ld, vulkan

The error it throws:

```
g++ -m64 -std=c++17 main.cpp -o vulkanprogram -lvulkan
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvulkan
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

what ld returns when I find it myself:

```
ld -lvulkan --verbose
attempt to open /usr/lib/libvulkan.so succeeded
/usr/lib/libvulkan.so
```

can someone help explain this to me?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Please pick only the relevant tag (looks like C++ in this case).

Comment: happens with C as well this is just a demonstration.

Comment: Check whether library is 32 bit and not 64 bit.

Comment: x86_64 vulkan library

Comment: Trying using explicit path: g++ -m64 -std=c++17 main.cpp -o vulkanprogram `/usr/lib/libvulkan.so`. It will tell you if the problem is with the path, or with the file. Looks like  a path problem, but better to check. Also, suggesting to try gcc for troubleshooting (c++ is more complex)

Comment: @dash-o that worked, but what can I do to solve this problem long term?

Comment: @Mutaru, can you share all environment variables related to ld (env | grep LD) ? Most likely, one of them prevents searching thru /usr/lib.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `ld` cannot search the correct path

use this before running: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib`

or this `g++ -m64 -std=c++17 main.cpp -o vulkanprogram -I/usr/include/ -L/usr/lib/ -lvulkan`

Comment: @Mutaru use this command to check the library: `readelf -h /usr/lib/libvulkan.so*`

Comment: @Mutaru note that u should use `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib` **in the same shell which u run g++...**

Comment: @Mutaru other way to resolve this is to use `g++ ... -I/usr/include/ -L/usr/lib/ -lvulkan`

Comment: @Mutaru don't be upset! :) , I don't know how much u know!

Comment: sorry I have been dealing with this problem for a couple days, and have gotten pretty annoyed at my pc.

Comment: @Mutaru no problem! just keep on it

Comment: @Mutaru take a look at `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` , `unset` it and `export` it again; sometimes it contains other paths, e.g. `/usr/local/lib/` instead of `/usr/lib/`

Comment: @Mutaru nope! `ld` can find that, but not through `g++`; be exact at what the linker says

Comment: @Mutaru try `which ld` to see your path of `ld`

Comment: /usr/bin/ld is the only path it returns

Comment: @Mutaru now try `/usr/bin/ld -lvulkan --verbose` to see if this works

Comment: same thing as when I ran it just as ld: attempt to open /usr/lib/libvulkan.so succeeded

Comment: @Mutaru sounds so weird! So, there is no problem with your linker at all! r u cross-compiling?!

Comment: No, and yes it is weird

Comment: @Mutaru I think the problem is somewhere else! its not about your linker! maybe it's about your `g++`! I can't help anymore because I don't know the whole situations! for further instruction: (1) build `vulkan` library from scratch and install it, (2) write a hello world just using one library `vulkan` (3) check again

Comment: @Mutaru or maybe there is a problem with `-std=c++17`

Comment: nope c++17 compiles just fine for a hello world program and it gives same error without it

Comment: to me, this looks like the permissions on the library file are not set correctly

Comment: or maybe on `/usr/lib/` directory!

Answer (score 0):

On surface, based on comments, the problem is with the LD search path. Providing the full path (/usr/lib/lib...) seems to address the problem.

```
g++ -m64 -std=c++17 main.cpp -o vulkanprogram /usr/lib/libvulkan.so
```

For permanent solution - troubleshoot with

- Verbose ld output: `g++ --Wl,--verbose m64 -std=c++17 main.cpp -o vulkanprogram /usr/lib/libvulkan.so`
- Check type of library `file /usr/lib/libvulkan.so`